# Binding an object array from my viewmodel to a javascript variable for fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm getting my fullcalendar events in an object array and storing it in my view model to pass to javascript so that I can load them into my full calendar events like below. But I'm getting an error when storing it in the scripts section as eventArray!

my service layer...

```
SpaceEventsViewModel viewModel = new SpaceEventsViewModel();

            var eventList = from e in events
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.SpaceEventId,
                                title = e.Title,
                                start = e.EventDateTime
                            };

            viewModel.EventArray = eventList.ToArray();

            return viewModel;
```

here is my view model...

```
public class SpaceEventsViewModel
{
    public object[] EventArray { get; set; }
}
```

here in my view where I try to set the EventArray to a js variable to use to load full calendars events, looking at what's in the variable 'eventsArray' I see this (not the array of event data) - eventsArray =

> "<>f__AnonymousType44`3[System.Int32,System.String,System.DateTime][]"

```
<script>
    var eventsArray = "@Model.EventArray";
</script>
```

so I get an error because this isn't the correct data full calendar needs.

ultimately I want to pass the eventsArray to my full calendar events option like this:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                //defaultDate: '2016-12-17',
                header: {
                    left: 'title', //today',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prev,next'
                },
                defaultView: 'month',
                editable: false,
                allDaySlot: false,
                selectable: true,
                eventStartEditable: false,
                //height: 300,
                //eventColor: 'green',
                events: [ eventsArray ]
  });
```

I tried changing a few things but received this error. I think it's because there are quotes around each value and that's not the correct syntax for events for fullcalendar.

"Expected ';'"

coming from the string of data passed to the view that looks like this

[image]

changed the viewmodel to this

```
public class SpaceEventsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<FullCalendarEvent> EventArray { get; set; }
}

public class FullCalendarEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

and the service code to this

```
var eventList = from e in Events
                            select new FullCalendarEvent
                            {
                                Id = e.SpaceEventId,
                                Title = e.Title,
                                Start = e.EventDateTime
                            };

            viewModel.EventArray = eventList;

            return viewModel;
```

I changed the html to this

```
<script>
    var eventsArray = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EventArray))";
</script>
```

I changed the DateTime property to a string for full calendar which is the corect format but I'm still getting this as an error

[image]

Comment: It needs to be `var eventsArray = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EventArray))';`, but pass a collection of a model containing those 2 properties (`id`, `title` and `start`)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the answer, can you give a short example of the second part of your answer. I'm having a hard time understanding what that means when you say "pass a collection of a model containing those 2 properties (id, title and start)"

Comment: Delete `public object[] EventArray { get; set; }` in your `SpaceEventsViewModel` and add properties `int id`, `string title` and `DateTime start`. The change the query to `select new SpaceEventsViewModel { id = e.SpaceEventId, .... }` and pass `IEnumerable<SpaceEventsViewModel>` to the view (and then it will be `'@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'`

Comment: ok let me give that a try...

Comment: I'm getting some syntax error in the string of data. Please look at my edit in the thread above. I'll post now.

Comment: There are a couple of issues. (1) The property names are quoted which they should not be - are you sure your not also trying to serialize it in the GET method?

Comment: And there will likely be a problem with your dates. Not sure what format your plugin expects them in, but you will probably need to make `Start` a `string` and format the `DateTime` to a `string` in the controller. Note also in the plugin it will be just `events: eventsArray`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131111/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user1186050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fullcalendar plugin requires an array of javascript objects for the `events` options, and the property names need to be lowercase.

Change the model to

```
public class FullCalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
}
```

and in the script

```
var eventsArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EventArray)) // no quotes
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ....
    events: eventsArray // not in brackets
});
```